# Why do I get the LWJGL Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have just started out learning lwjgl to make games in java. This is my first lwjgl project and I get these following errors:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more
```

This is my code that I used:

```
 package main;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        long window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Window", 0, 0);
        

        
        GLFWVidMode videoMode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        glfwSetWindowPos(window, (videoMode.width()+ 640) / 2, (videoMode.height() + 480) / 2);
        
        glfwShowWindow(window);
        
        while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }



}
```

I am sorry if this is something obvious. I have not used this library until this point.

Comment: It seems that the code for the `org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode` class is not in the classpath when Java is trying to run your code.  Why this is the case is a matter of how you're packaging and running your application.  If you're running the `java` command yourself, then you need to provide a `classpath` argument that tells Java where to find this missing class and probably other classes used by it.

Comment: Can you tell us how you are compiling and running your code?  How do you expect that Java is finding the `lwjgl` library?

Comment: I tried to use the 'export to jar' function in built in eclipse. I also tried running it in the editor and the program still didnt load and that error was still there

Comment: It isn't a matter of your own code, but rather how you're making the dependent module(s) available to Java.  In Eclipse, you must be able to specify what modules your code depends on.  (I'm an IntelliJ guy) Have you set this up in any way?  If you have, when you run your code in Eclipse, it should construct a proper `classpath` argument and pass it to Java so that your dependencies are found when your code runs.